# FileNotFoundError is showing in django code when attempting to extract JSON data in a python file

Tags: python, json, django

I am trying to extract and input data into a JSON file from python code in the views.py file of a django webapp, but once I run the server, I get a FileNotFoundError for the prices.json and the accountInfo.json files, altoughh the directory is correct from where the file is. I tried doing "./filename" to indicate that it is in the current directory, but that has not worked either.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ListForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
import json

robinUser = ''
robinPass = ''
capitalToInvest = 0

def MakeMoney(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ListForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            robinUser = form.cleaned_data['robinUser']
            robinPass = form.cleaned_data['robinPass']
            capitalToInvest = form.cleaned_data['capitalToInvest']
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/index.html/')
    else:
        form = ListForm()

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})

def getJSON(filePathAndName):
    with open(filePathAndName, 'r') as fp:
        return json.load(fp)

def overwriteJSON(data):
    with open("./prices.json", 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)

def StartProgram(request):
    rawJSON = getJSON('templates/prices.json')
    rawJSON['capital'] = int(capitalToInvest)
    with open('templates/prices.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(rawJSON, fp)
    rawJSON2 = getJSON('templates/accountInfo.json')
    rawJSON2['email'] = robinUser
    rawJSON2['pass'] = robinPass
    with open("templates/accountInfo.json", 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(rawJSON2, fp)

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Here is the error message:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'templates\\prices.json'
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: import os and then put this os.path.join('templates/prices/json') instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try serving this JSON as a static file

Read more in the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/